# How to replace text with substitute that contains JSX code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
interface ICard {
  content: string,
  blanks: Array<{word: string, hidden: boolean}>
}
  function processCards():Array<any>{
    if (cards !==null ){
      const text = cards.map((card,cardIndex)=>{
        var content = card.content
        card.blanks.map((blank,blankIndex)=>{
          // replace content
          const visibility = (blank.hidden)?'hidden':'visible'
          const click_blank = <span className={visibility} onClick={()=>toggleBlank(cardIndex,blankIndex)}>{blank.word}</span>
          content = content.replace(blank.word,click_blank) 
        })  
        return content
      })
      return text
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }
```

I have an array of objects of type ICard.
Whenever card.blanks.word appears in card.content, I want to wrap that word in  tags that contain a className style AND an onClick parameter.

It seems like I can't just replace the string using content.replace like I've tried, as replace() does not like the fact I have JSX in the code.

Is there another way to approach this problem?

Comment: What's being assigned to content when you do `card.content`?

Comment: its a paragraph of text (string)

Comment: The `replace` method works with strings. Are you sure it is being assigned to this type?

Comment: Yes, its definitely a string. Here is the Typescript error I get: [tsserver 2769] [E] No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string'.
      Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(substring: string, ...args: any[]): string'.

Comment: I don't understand the error, but I think the issue is I'm trying to replace string with JSX. If I set card.content to type JSX.Element, then I lose my replace() function entirely, so that isnt the answer either

Comment: Try replacing JSX with a string, wrapping the JSX with quotes for instance. It may clarify what's the actual problem

Comment: That will make it replace it with a string, which works. But now I have no way to make it render it properly, since it thinks its a string.

Comment: What's the structure of what you are trying to replace? Can't you just return a `<span> className={visibility} onClick={()=>toggleBlank(cardIndex,blankIndex)}>{blank.word}</span>` inheriting some attributes of what you want to change?

Comment: The structure is a paragraph of raw text. A string. I need words in that paragraph to be wrapped in <span> and contain onClick functionality.

Comment: It's hard without a minimal reproducible example. Last guess, your map needs to return JSX and in this `card.blanks.map((blank,blankIndex)` seems to have no return

Comment: It does not need a return. It is performing substitutions on var content = card.content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct a new `ReactElement` from the parts of string preceding and following each `blank.word`, with the new `span` stuck in the middle. You can do this by iteratively building an array and then returning it wrapped in `<>` (`<React.Fragment>`). Here's a (javascript) example:

```js
export default function App() {
  const toggleBlankPlaceholder = (cardIndex, blankIndex) => {};
  const cardIndexPlaceholder = 0;
  const blanks = [
    { word: "foo", hidden: true },
    { word: "bar", hidden: false },
  ];
  const content = "hello foo from bar!";

  const res = [content];
  for (const [blankIndex, { word, hidden }] of blanks.entries()) {
    const re = new RegExp(`(.*?)${word}(.*)`);
    const match = res[res.length - 1].match(re);
    if (match) {
      const [, prefix, suffix] = match;
      res[res.length - 1] = prefix;
      const visibility = hidden ? "hidden" : "visible";
      res.push(
        <span
          className={visibility}
          onClick={() =>
            toggleBlankPlaceholder(cardIndexPlaceholder, blankIndex)
          }
        >
          {word}
        </span>
      );
      res.push(suffix);
    }
  }
  return <>{res}</>;
}
```

The returned value will be `hello <span class="hidden">foo</span> from <span class="visible">bar</span>!`

A couple of things:

1. In your example, you used `map` over `card.blanks` *without* consuming the value. Please don't do that! If you don't intend to use the new array that `map` creates, use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead.
2. In my example, I assumed for simplicity that each entry in `blanks` occurs 0 or 1 times *in order* in `content`. Your usage of `replace` in your example code would only have replaced the first occurrence of `blank.word` (see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)), though I'm not sure that's what you intended. Your code *did not* make an ordering assumption, so you'll need to rework my example code a little depending on the desired behavior.

Comment: Don't you need to match the start and end? `^(.*?)${word}(.*)`$ ?

Comment: @cucaracho, no, the expressions with and without anchors are equivalent, provided that there are no newlines in the text (`.` matches every non-newline character). The expression says, "starting from the beginning, match zero or more non-newline characters until the *first* occurrence of `word` (hence the `?`), then match zero or more non-newline characters, proceeding until text is exhausted, i.e. to the end."